# QGIS spatialite db errors

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, spatialite

I recently upgraded QGIS by building QGIS 2.11 from source against GDAL 2.0 on my Ubuntu 14.04 system. After a few teething troubles I got it to compile using QT creator. I now find that I can't open any spatialite databases e.g. openstreetmap with the error being returned:

`obsolete libspatialite: connecting to this DB requires using v.4.0 (or any subsequent)`

When I check it appears that QGIS was built against SpatialLite Version 4.1.1 so not really sure what has happened here. I can connect to all of my old spatialite dbs using the DB Manager in QGIS which allows me to view the attribute tables (but no previews). If I try and 'add to canvas' from DB Manager I get an error message telling me to check the logs with the following output:

`dbname='/home/dori.osm.db' table="dori_buildings" (geometry) sql= is an invalid layer - not loaded`

Equally I can explore the data with the QSpatiaLite plugin but if I try and load the data from the plugin into QGIS I get the following error:

> Impossible to Load table 'dori_buildings' into QGIS

Anyone have any ideas what's happening here - did I miss out a dependency when building perhaps?